# Excel CheckBox Select Range of Chart

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2013

```
Option Explicit

Public PlotName As String
Public PlotRange As Range

Sub Tester()
Range("TCKWH.V.1").Select
AddPlot ActiveSheet.Range("C9:C13,D9:O13")
End Sub

Sub AddPlot(rng As Range)
 With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    PlotName = .Name
    .Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(rng.Address())

.Chart.HasTitle = True
.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = Range("C9")

End With
Set PlotRange = rng
Application.EnableEvents = False
rng.Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub RemovePlot(rng As Range)
If Not PlotRange Is Nothing Then
    If Application.Intersect(rng, PlotRange) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        rng.Parent.Shapes(PlotName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
RemovePlot Target
End Sub
```

I have this code that creates a graph, based on the information that was accepted through a check box. But any account you do not select appears as a "blank" legend entry
Is there a macro code to delete "blank" legend entries?

[image]

Comment: You're setting the `Source Range:=Range("C9:O13")` . Rather than setting the `Source` data, you will need to add/remove `Series` data using the `Series.XValues` and `Series.Values` and `Series.Name` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the table create another table. Then link the checkboxes to the table below the first table. Then after True/False enter `=IF($B10=TRUE,C3,"")`

After that replace AddPlot `ActiveSheet.Range("C9:C13,D9:O13")` with the range of the bottom table.

[image]

Comment: New Question. Concerning the red and green line on the legend is there a way to make it disappear when a variable is not selected.